# iOS web form attributes

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, webforms

I'm building a web page that will only be used on the iPad.  I have a textbox that I'm using for users to enter an email address.  I know that there is a form element you can set that changes the default ipad/iPhone keyboard to show the @ symbol so you don't have to hit any special buttons to get to it but having a hard time figuring out what it is.  Anyone know?

I have found adding autocapitalization="false" will keep it from capitalizing but can't find how to tell it its an email textbox.

Comment: Does: <input type="email" /> ...not work?

Comment: well i'm using a .net web form, i never thought of putting type behind it.  I'll try it and see how it works.

Comment: Safari Developer Library: ["Supported Input Values"](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html)

Comment: Safari Developer Library: ["Designing Forms"](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006512-SW1)

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="email">
```

Also useful:

```
<input type="number">
<input type="tel">
<input type="url">
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have found adding autocapitalization="false" will keep it from capitalizing

Actually, the correct syntax to prevent iOS capitalization is autocapitalize="off"